# How should apostrophes be used with parenthetical plurals?

Tags: apostrophe, parenthetical-plural

The following two sentences make sense; the first is where there's one system with one or more associated databases, the second is where there's multiple systems with one or more databases:

```
Backup the system's database(s).

Backup the systems' database(s).
```

What convention should be used when there may be multiple systems?  e.g.

```
Backup the system((')s(')) database(s).
```

Comment: Try this link-:http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/11/much-ado-about-possessive-apostrophes/

Comment: @Argot There's even a *blogoverflow*?

Comment: Ans: *Backup the **systems'** databases.* No confusion. By the way, never use *databases(s)* -- there's no such thing.

Comment: @Kris: It does cause confusion when there are multiple systems but only one database (I find it hard to envisage but it's part of the question).

Comment: @Kris; sorry, that was a typo on my part; corrected.

Comment: @TimLymington; good point for the second example there probably would always be multiple databases given there are multiple systems; though I such things can exists (e.g. transactional system and data warehouse which uses the transactional system's db as the source of ETL could be a common scenario where two systems could be said to share the same database).

Comment: @Argot; thanks for the link; useful stuff though I couldn't find anything on parenthetical plurals.

Comment: Backup the system's(s')databases. Source: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389421/use-of-parentheses-to-include-both-singular-and-or-plural-possessive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider rewriting to eliminate the problem:

> Backup the system database(s).

If this isn't possible, I would probably go with *systems'*, plural. If you're worried about readers being excessively literal (which can happen with technical documentation, unfortunately), you can add clarifying language elsewhere, perhaps in a footnote.

Comment: Nice; if in doubt, dodge the issue.